# Import CSV file to Laravel controller and insert data to two tables

Tags: php, laravel, csv, laravel-5

So I am a complete noob to Laravel and am trying something here. I want to import a CSV file into two tables, I have a table called lists that will get the list name and a `client_id`.

Then I have a table called customers that will get name surname contact number as well as `client_id` and a `list_id`.

What I want to achieve is to import a CSV file that will take the file name and store it in the list table, then create an array through the CSV file and import the data into the customers table with the list and client id's.

I have the first part done, and it inserts into the lists table correctly, How do I now create an array from the CSV that is located in storage/documents and then insert that into the customers table?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Input;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ListsRequest;
use App\Lists;
use App\Clients;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ListsController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // $list_items = Lists::all();
        $clients = Clients::all();

        return view('lists.show', compact('clients'));
    }

    public function store(Requests\ListsRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->input();
        Lists::create($input);

        if (Input::hasFile('name'))
        {

            $file = Input::file('name');
            $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $path = storage_path('documents');

            $file->move($path, $name);

            // All works up to here
            // All I need now is to create an array
            // from the CSV and insert into the customers database
        }
    }
}
```

I chose to use the answer that I had accepted but I also played with the other answer and got it to work like this.

```
public function store(Requests\ListsRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->input();
    $client_id = $request->input('client_id');

    if (Input::hasFile('name'))
    {
        $file = Input::file('name');
        $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = storage_path('documents');

        Lists::create(['client_id' => $client_id, 'name' => $name]);

        $reader = Reader::createFromPath($file->getRealPath());
        // Create a customer from each row in the CSV file
        $headers = array();

        foreach ($reader as $index => $row)
        {
            if ($index === 0)
            {
                $headers = $row;
            } else
            {
                $data = array_combine($headers, $row);
                Customers::create($data);
            }
        }

        $file->move($path, $name);

        return view('clients');
    }
}
```

Comment: look at this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063008/upload-csv-file-and-import-it-to-database-using-laravel you can not just direct insert to database like you do, if the link does not provide help, let me know

Comment: Am trying this now :) Thank you, will let you know how it goes in a few

Comment: Okay so I tried what is seen in the edited question above, but now I just get blank screen even if I just return 'hello' where I have

Comment: Could you help explain the logic in the area where I added?

Comment: it is important to make step by step problem solving, so if it does not return hello, this means it is not got the file or your if statement is returning false, try for fun to write dd($input) before if statement to see if your controller is life and find out if $input contain the things you expected

Comment: it seems that if I die and dump input before the if I get an array, but after the iff seems empty.

Comment: Am I maybe supposed to do something with the file before this?

Comment: So I guess you have a form you upload file to and then want to move that file content to your database 1 and database 2, is that correct, if yes, have you made your form to accept files?

Comment: I believe so, my form opens like this {!! Form::open(null, ['files'=> true, 'url' => 'lists']) !!}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102682/discussion-between-maytham-mahiam-and-devin-gray).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are 3 steps to read CSV file and import it in database in Laravel.

1. Read CSV file
2. Convert it to array
3. Finally create records in our database.

Before we start, I have created a sample `test.csv` file and put it on my public folder under file folder:

```
name,email,password
user1,email1@email.com,pasxxxxxxxxxword
user2,email2@email.com,pasxxxxxxxxxword
user3,email3@email.com,pasxxxxxxxxxword
```

Step 1 and 2; I created a helper function called `csvToArray`, I just put it in my controller for now (this function is inspired from this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)) it simply reads the CSV file and convert it to array:

```
function csvToArray($filename = '', $delimiter = ',')
{
    if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return false;

    $header = null;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== false)
        {
            if (!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Step 3; And here is my final step, read array and insert it in our database:

```
public function importCsv()
{
    $file = public_path('file/test.csv');

    $customerArr = $this->csvToArray($file);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($customerArr); $i ++)
    {
        User::firstOrCreate($customerArr[$i]);
    }

    return 'Jobi done or what ever';    
}
```

> **Note:** this solution assume that you have a model in your Laravel project and has the proper table in your database.

if you use `dd($customerArr)` you will get this
[image]

Comment: I think this is a good aproach. But wath about with a large CSV like 100 000 rows? The array will have a big size and i could have problema with the memory ram.

Comment: The header in this case depending on your data model as mentioned in the note.in my case it is user model and it contains name, email password. you do your own and give it a try. if i have misunderstood you please let me know.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Can you just tell me, how do you even bcrypt the password after getting the csv file uploaded?

Comment: @ToxifiedHashkey I have stopped working with laravel few years now. but the bcrypt function you can google it and find a function to bcrypt the password. but $customerArr[$i] is each object you import,  you can conceptually do some thing like with out testing it and validating it.

$customerArr[$i]->password = bcryptFunction($customerArr[$i]->password) 

This will overwrite text password with bcrypted password.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Thans alot for that tip :D

Answer (score 10):

In your `store()` method, create the record in your `lists` table, and then iterate over the contents of the CSV file and insert the data into the `customers` table. You should create a [relation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) between customers and lists for this purpose. You would also be better off using something like the [PHP League’s CSV package](http://csv.thephpleague.com/) for reading such files:

```php
public function store(AddCustomersRequest $request)
{
    // Get uploaded CSV file
    $file = $request->file('csv');

    // Create list name
    $name = time().'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

    // Create a list record in the database
    $list = List::create(['name' => $name]);

    // Create a CSV reader instance
    $reader = Reader::createFromFileObject($file->openFile());

    // Create a customer from each row in the CSV file
    foreach ($reader as $index => $row) {
        $list->customers()->create($row);
    }

    // Redirect back to where you need with a success message
}
```

Comment: I used the function from @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ to do this, but I also played around with your answer to see how to get this done, I am editing my question for you to see.

Answer (score 4):

@maytham The solution by Maytham will work well. However, it will have a huge problem if you're trying to do with large data. Even if you do 1000 rows, it will create a problem, as it will make 1000 insert statement separately. I will just edit the third method by him and add my own input

```
public function importCsv()
{
    $file = public_path('file/test.csv');

    $customerArr = $this->csvToArray($file);
    $data = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($customerArr); $i ++)
    {
        $data[] = [
            'column_name1' => 'value',
            'column_name2' => 'value2',
            .. so..on..and..on
        ];
        //User::firstOrCreate($customerArr[$i]);
    }
    DB::table('table_name')->insert($data);
    return 'Jobi done or what ever';    
}
```

This will call the database once to insert as many rows as you wish. Be it 1000, 100000 or whatever.
*However, if you have a huge csv, this will be a problem too since you will be required to insert in chunks. Like in PostgreSQL, I have noticed that you can insert up to 65000 something rows in one statement. Maybe I am wrong about the number but there's a limit in every database and you need to look for that.*

Comment: Yes, that's a very good point. If you have a large CSV file, you very likely can't store it all in an array in memory before you start inserting the data into the DB, so you need to be inserting the data in chunks as you read it from the CSV file. Thanks.

Comment: Correct. I also saw that there's a limitation to the number of rows in one insert.